# Recs on getting started with Django on Heroku, with Pycharm

Tags: python, django, heroku, pycharm, gunicorn

I've been trying for a couple of days to get my first Django app up on Heroku, mainly following Heroku's instructions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django —

(The background: for those interested, I'm a Django newbie who's created his first app and I thought I'd put it online to show it off as part of my portfolio. Not so easy!  My shared-hosting web host said: nothing doing.   So I looked through various things and came on Heroku, which is a bit pricey for me to use as a web host, but at least I could practice deployment.)

But I'm having a great deal of trouble. I deinstalled my regular pythons and installed homebrew and all that, finally got Pycharm to play nicely with my Homebrew python, but can't get gunicorn to work within Pycharm, can't get foreman to work as it can't find gunicorn (although gunicorn is installed into Pycharm's virtual env), etc.

I know both that I don't have a lot of idea what I'm doing (I'm still trying to grok Django) and that it would be difficult for anyone to troubleshoot my situation.  I'm curious to know if anyone can suggest a step-by-step — taking the Heroku link as a starting point up until where it says to run foreman — that I could follow to proceed.  A link would be super-helpful.  I'm a good programmer, but really haven't tackled all these setup intricacies before, or deal with WSGI issues or anything like that).

Thanks, I know it's a bit vague, but I'm a bit blinded by the light at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite the answer you're looking for, but if you come over and give us a try at [PythonAnyhwere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), we specialise in Python hosting, we provide lots of instructions on how to get going with django, and are very happy to help you if you run into any problems....